# URLSession returns script element still string encoded and escaped

Tags: swift, unicode, urlsession, urlrequest

I am making the below request to Youtube using `URLRequest` and `URLSession`. Most of the response looks fine, however I found that some of the script elements that are being returned have what seem to be escaped encoded characters such as `{ } [ ] = ' "` in the form of `\\x7b \\x7d \\x5b \\x5d \\x22 \\x3d \\x27`

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPHWVzGcW-iozudjp8U984g/")
        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] (data, response, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
            }

            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
            }
          
        }
        task.resume()
```

I have done this request in Java using `okhttp3` and I didn't see any encoding left in these script elements there, and they also seem just fine doing a source inspection in multiple browsers.

I tried to remove them by using replacingOccurrences which works, but for some reason the JSON is still malformed, so I must be missing some of the other weird encoding being returned. Is there any built in way to remove this encoding, or to get `URLSession` to not leave it encoded?

Here is a a sample:

```
<script nonce=\"koFDr1miSKW8U9aJTnGQVw\">var ytInitialData = \'\\x7b\\x22responseContext\\x22:\\x7b\\x22serviceTrackingParams\\x22:\\x5b\\x7b\\x22service\\x22:\\x22GFEEDBACK\\x22,\\x22params\\x22:\\x5b\\x7b\\x22key\\x22:\\x22browse_id\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x22UCPHWVzGcW-iozudjp8U984g\\x22\\x7d,\\x7b\\x22key\\x22:\\x22logged_in\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x220\\x22\\x7d,\\x7b\\x22key\\x22:\\x22e\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x2224022617,24023962,24014268,24022308,23968386,24022875,24025790,24025869,23857948,24006666,24022914,23923339,23976696,23983296,23944779,23744176,23990877,24021968,24021668,23966208,24011119,23891346,24006795,24023271,24001373,23934970,23987676,23897180,23891344,23804281,23974595,24016478,24007246,24012654,24024964,1714255,24002010,23946420,23997485,23884386,24019883,23882502,23918597,24012117,23969934,24014440\\x22\\x7d\\x5d\\x7d,\\x7b\\x22service\\x22:\\x22CSI\\x22,\\x22params\\x22:\\x5b\\x7b\\x22key\\x22:\\x22c\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x22MWEB\\x22\\x7d,\\x7b\\x22key\\x22:\\x22cver\\x22,\\x22value\\x22:\\x222.20210406.03.00\\x22\\x7d,\\x7b\\x22key\\x22:\\x22yt_li\\x22,\\x2"..
```

Comment: I don't see any json response only html. Show how you are getting the initial data from your html response

Comment: @LeoDabus The JSON is embedded in a few of the script elements inside of the HTML I noticed that while I was going to www.youtube.com I was being served m.youtube.com on the response. I was able to resolve the issue by changing my user agent to a desktop Mozilla user agent string.

Comment: How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

While inspecting the response further I realized that while I was making a request to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) I was receiving a response from m.youtube.com I changed my user agent field to a desktop Mozilla string by adding the following

request.setValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0", forHTTPHeaderField:"user-agent")

Most of my encoding issues were resolved, now I was receiving &quot html encoding for all of my quotation characters. I went ahead and replaced all of those with " using replacingOccurrences and the JSON now had a valid format.